# watchOS 2.0 running watchOS 1.0 apps?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, backwards-compatibility, watchos-2, watchos

I understand Apple watchOS 2.0 apps will require some modification (particularly in regards to bi-directional communication) ....

But, what about all the Watch apps already in the App Store written for 1.0, will they run "as is" on watchOS 2.0 without modification? Is new code/modification necessary only for apps that want to take advantage of new features in 2.0?

In Summary, what if I don't want to take advantage of any of the new features in 2.0 (yet), and I want  to leave my 1.0 app exactly "as is", will those users who upgrade to to watchOS 2.0 still be able to download and run my app?

I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this question in any of the Apple Watch dev forums? Any information greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did find this thread in the Apple Developer forums:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5567

However, there are several contradictory posts in the thread regarding whether or not watchOS 1.0 apps that rely on App Groups and openParentApplication/handleWatchKitExtensionRequest for bi-directional communication will run un-modified on watchOS 2.0.

Comment: I have everything pretty much working the way I want for the immediate time being (sharing data and messages between phone and watch via App Groups and  openParentApplication/handleWatchKitExtensionRequest) and would like to delay the transition to watchOS 2.0 a bit longer -- although, if an app that targets 1.0 won't open on a Watch running watchOS 2.0 then I have no choice but to update my app(s) before the September release.

Comment: So my question remains, will it still be possible to write & deploy apps that target only 1.0 (apps that use App Groups and  openParentApplication) and expect them run unmodified "as is" on devices with watchOS 2.0 installed?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Apple migration docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/) you should be able to:

> Do you need to support earlier versions of Apple Watch?
>
> You can deliver Watch apps for both watchOS 1 and watchOS 2 in the
>   same iOS app bundle, but doing so means maintaining separate targets
>   and executables for each. Because it runs on Apple Watch, a Watch app
>   for watchOS 2 must be completely recompiled into a separate
>   executable. And because of the architectural differences between the
>   platforms, sharing code may be more effort and add more complexity
>   than having two separate apps.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the only explicit answers I have found indicate that **watchOS 1 apps do run on watchOS 2 devices.**

See a similar question I asked on Apple Developer forums:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14781

While one person responded that Apple's transition guide indicated watchOS 1 apps *wouldn't* run on watchOS 2, I couldn't find that anywhere after searching the guide thoroughly. Perhaps he misread it.

I've recently installed iOS 9 and watchOS 2 on my devices. All apps with a paired watch app show up on the watch, but they were hanging on launch. This might be a problem with iOS 9 compatibility (these were probably iOS 8 apps) or general bugginess with the Betas. I will update you once I re-test.

Answer (score 0):

They will not be able to have your app native if that is what you mean. Also, apps must all be watchOS 2 by now.